# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'DataAccessLayer.faturaozellikleri get_Item(Int32)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have a method that was working but after I used a custom connection string, it's worked...

```
public void ShiftBillNumber(List<faturaozellikleri> shiftBillNumberList,int  accrual)
{           
  var faturaOzellikleri = new faturaozellikleri();

  for (int i = 0; i < shiftBillNumberList.Count; i++)
  {
    faturaOzellikleri = shiftBillNumberList[i];

   if (i != shiftBillNumberList.Count - 1)
   {
     if (faturaOzellikleri.FaturaSeriID != shiftBillNumberList[i + 1].FaturaSeriID)
     {
      shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaNo = shiftBillNumberList[i + 1].FaturaNo;
      shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaSeriID = shiftBillNumberList[i + 1].FaturaSeriID;
      shiftBillNumberList[i].SeriNo = shiftBillNumberList[i + 1].SeriNo;
     }
     else
     {
      shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaNo = shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaNo + accrual;
     }
   }
   else
  {

   var activeSerial =ent.faturaserileri.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaSeriID);

      *********************** 
    ****************

      ent.SaveChanges();

    }

  }
 }
```

the problem has been ocurred in the last else

```
   var activeSerial =ent.faturaserileri.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaSeriID);
```

it was work but now it doesnt work.. I tried like that (seperate it as two parts

```
var xx = ent.faturaserileri.Select(s => s);

var activeSerial = xx.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaSeriID);
```

but i get the same error..

"faturaozellikleri" is the name of a table in my database and I use entity framework..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF is trying to translate the part `shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaSeriID` into SQL, but is has not translation for that. If you first put it into a variable you'll be OK:

```
var id = shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaSeriID;    
var activeSerial = ent.faturaserileri.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == id);
```

The value of the variable `id` will now be transferred as query parameter.

Comment: aha i got it.. but i dont understand why it was working earlier.. now everything is fine.. thank you. i will accept it as the right answer 5 mins later :)

Comment: Maybe you did it in linq-to-objects before, i.e. after an `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try assiging shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaSeriID to a variable (int or whatever) and then call the function.

```
var sampleID = shiftBillNumberList[i].FaturaSeriID;
var activeSerial =ent.faturaserileri.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == sampleID );
```

This might work.